# Error reCAPTCHAv3 en form php

Tags: php, mysql, google-api, recaptcha

este es mi problema, siguiendo los pasos de Google y modificando a mis intereses lo necesario, me salta siempre el mismo error, para poneros en contexto:

Así tengo el form:

```
            //reCAPTCHAv3
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6LfzTM4lAAAAANgiA61919I_QtPqQgvt6eC9ZRWg"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#login_form').click(function() {
                    grecaptcha.ready(function() {
                        grecaptcha.execute('6LfzTM4lAAAAANgiA61919I_QtPqQgvt6eC9ZRWg', {
                            action: 'validarUsuario'
                        }).then(function(token) {
                            $('login_form').prepend('<input type='hidden' name='token' value="' + token + '" ')
                            $('login_form').prepend('<input type='hidden' name='action' value="' + validarUsuario + '" ')
                            $('login-form').submit();
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <article>
            <h1>Registro</h1>
            <form id="login_form" action="registrarse2.php" method="GET"">
            <hr>
                <label id="icon" for="name"><i class="icon-user"></i></label>
                <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" required/>
                <label id="icon" for="name"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></label>
                <input type="email" name="correo" id="correo" placeholder="Correo" required/>
                <label id="icon" for="name"><i class="icon-shield"></i></label>
                <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Contraseña" required/>
                <label id="icon" for="name"><i class="icon-check"></i></label>
                <input type="password" name="pass2" id="pass2" placeholder="Repita la contraseña" required/>
            <hr>
                <pre><br><a><input type="radio" value="padre" name="opcion" required> Soy padre     <a> <input type="radio" value="alumno" name="opcion" required> Soy alumno</a></pre>
                <div class="gender"><p><input type="checkbox" name="politica" id="politica" required> Ha leido y acepta todas nuestras políticas</p></div>
                <input type="submit" id="entrar" name="enviar"  class="botones" value="ACEPTAR">  
            
            </form><br>
```

El formulario funciona perfectamente pero algo me estoy dejando porque no me salta de decir que soy un robot, el recaptcha "funciona", lo que no es el código en esta página:

```
            <?php
        define ('CLAVE', '6LfzTM4lAAAAAPBxb5roJVMgaMzxtdHXf-Yshvna'); //CLAVE SECRETA(2)

        $token = $_POST['token'];
        $action = $_POST['action'];

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('secret' => CLAVE, 'response' => $token)));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        $datos=json_decode($response, true);

        if($datos['success'] == 1 && $datos['score'] >= 0.5)
        {
            // Captcha válido, continuar con el registro
            $nombre = $_REQUEST['usuario'];
            $correo = $_REQUEST['correo'];
            $pass = $_REQUEST['pass'];
            $pass2 = $_REQUEST["pass2"];
            $tipo_usuario = $_REQUEST["opcion"];
            $passencryp = MD5($pass);

            $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "rootroot") or die ("No se puede conectar con el servidor");
            mysqli_select_db($conexion, "educados") or die ("No se puede seleccionar la base de datos");

            $correoexistente = "select correo from usuario where correo='$correo'";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $correoexistente);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0) {
                echo "<script language='javascript'>
                    alert('¡¡¡Su correo ya está registrado!!!');
                    window.location.replace('./registrarse.php');
                    </script>";
                } else {
                    $query = "insert into usuario (usuario, correo, contraseña, tipo_usuario) values ('$nombre','$correo','$passencryp','$tipo_usuario')";
                    if(mysqli_query ($conexion, $query)) {

                        echo "<script language='javascript'>
                            alert('¡¡¡Usuario creado!!! Se ha enviado un correo electrónico para confirmar tu dirección.');
                            window.location.replace('./inicio_sesión.php');
                            </script>"; 
                    } else {
                        echo "<script language='javascript'>
                            alert('¡¡¡Usuario no creado, compruebe los parámetros!!!');
                            window.location.replace('./registrarse.php');
                            </script>";
                    }
                }

                mysqli_close($conexion);

        } else {
            // Captcha inválido, mostrar mensaje de error
            echo "<script language='javascript'>
                            alert('¡¡¡Eres un robot!!!');
                            window.location.replace('./registrarse.php');
                            </script>";
        }
        ?>
```

Se que el formulario el cual se encarga de hacer el insert en la bbdd está bien ya que funciona perfectamente y he resumido ambos php, para que esté más compacto.

Espero que veais el problema, muchas gracias de antemano